# error when I am trying to install pyaudio on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: python, include, portaudio

I know this questions was asked couple of times, but all the answers do not work for me.
I get this error when I try to install PyAudio:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building pyaudio using PEP 517
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/a/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:31:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
      #include "portaudio.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

From what I can tell, it's ignoring the global portaudio and looking for another one ?
I removed and installed already portaudio with brew, I update everything, I installed command line for Xcode, I tried with anaconda in notebook, same error there as well. I already tried to installed wheel and said its fulfilled.
Where to put this portaudio file so it see it ?
Any suggestions to fix this error ?
Thanks

Comment: I found this and tried ```LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix portaudio)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix portaudio)/include" pip install pyaudio
``` but after I run main.py I get this error ```AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Comment: isn't it strange that if I run pip show pyaudio its showing me the location of it ? But when I run main.py it says "Could not find PyAudio; check installation"